# Error while trying to upload file conversion types mismatch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have folowing entety.

```
package com.example.model;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;

@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")

public class Documents {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

     @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, updatable = false)
        @CreatedDate
    private Date date_created;

     @Column(name = "name")
     private String name;

     @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "type_id", nullable = false)
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        private Documenttypes typeid;
     @Column(name = "file")
     private String file;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public Date getDate_created() {
        return date_created;
    }
    public void setDate_created(Date date_created) {
        this.date_created = date_created;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Documenttypes getTypeid() {
        return typeid;
    }
    public void setTypeid(Documenttypes typeid) {
        this.typeid = typeid;
    }
    public String getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
    }


}
```

One of the fields called file is to upload the document. And the controller function for this is as follows:

```
 public ModelAndView add(@ModelAttribute("documentsForm") Documents documents,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)
     {
        //upload
         if (file.isEmpty()) {
             return new ModelAndView("redirect:/document/list");
                
            }
           try {
               byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
               Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + file.getOriginalFilename());
            documents.setFile("test");
               Files.write(path, bytes);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         //end
         documentsService.addDocument(documents);
         return new ModelAndView("redirect:/document/list");
         
     }
```

But then I try to upload file and submit a form I am getting this exception Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'file'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframewo

Full error is:

```
2021-10-15 12:44:35.029  WARN 13500 --- [nio-8888-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.validation.BindException: org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult: 1 errors
Field error in object 'documentsForm' on field 'file': rejected value [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile@2c2feacc]; codes [typeMismatch.documentsForm.file,typeMismatch.file,typeMismatch.java.lang.String,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [documentsForm.file,file]; arguments []; default message [file]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'file'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile' to required type 'java.lang.String' for property 'file': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]]
```

Comment: It would be best if you could provide the complete error message; this one is truncated.

Comment: Added a full error text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@ModelAttribute` will enable data binding from the HTTP request to `@ModelAttribute` instance.

It will try to bind the value from the query parameter , field name of the form data and others (see [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-initbinder)) to the `@ModelAttribute` instance 's field provided that their names are matched.

In your case , as your controller method has a query parameter called file , it will try to bind its value to the `Documents` 's file field. As the file query parameter is in `MultipartFile` type but `Documents` is in `String` type , it requires conversion but there are no `Converter` registered for doing it.

Not sure if you really want to bind the content of the `MultipartFile` to the `Documents` 's file field. If not, you can simply rename either one such that they are not matched.

Otherwise, you can implement a `Converter` to convert `MultipartFile` to `String` :

```java
 public class MulitpartConverter implements Converter<MultipartFile, String> {

        @Override
        public String convert(MultipartFile source) {
            try {
                return new String(source.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Fail to convert multipart file to string", e);
            }
        }
    }
```

And register it :

```java
    @Configuration
    public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
            @Override
            public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
                registry.addConverter(new MulitpartConverter());
            }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Renaming did help. Now I will try to bind a filename to that field in db.